# Defining prior on variance and not precision

Tags: bayesian, bugs

I know that WinBugs uses precision as a parameter in dnorm instead of variance

```
 model {

    #Likelihood
        for(i in 1:N1){
            y1[i] ~dnorm(mu,tau)
        }

    sigma <- sqrt(1/tau)

    #Priors
    mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    tau~ dgamma(taumu, taus)
   }
```

My question is: if instead I want to specify the prior for sigma because I know its mean and variance would it be right to use the following model ?

```
  model {

    #Likelihood
        for(i in 1:N1){
            y1[i] ~dnorm(mu,tau)
        }

    tau <- sqrt(1/sigma)

    #Priors
    mu ~ dnorm(0,0.000001)
    sigma ~ dnorm(sigmamu, sigmas)
   }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: you cannot put a normal prior on a positive quantity.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks I understand it but I have that the variance is normally distributed with mean sigmamu and std sigmas so how can I do to convert these information into precision?

Comment: If you know or set mean and variance for $\sigma$, then you can pick one and only one inverse gamma distribution with the same mean and variance. Or any other distribution on the positive real line with the same mean and variance. But you cannot "have that the variance is normally distributed" because this is impossible.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks but I think what I am trying to understand is given sigmamu and sigmas how I find the corresponding inverse gamma.

Comment: On the [Wikipedia page about the inverse gamma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution), the connection between natural parameters and mean and variance is available.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks. So if I calculate the shape parameters from the known sigmamu and sigmas values these are the parameters of the inverse gamma for the precision and not the variance?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20233/discussion-between-xian-and-user3706794).

Answer (score 1):

If "sigma <- sqrt(1/tau)" as indicated in the model on the top, then how is "tau <- sqrt(1/sigma)"?

$\sigma = 1/\sqrt\tau \implies \sigma^2 = 1/\tau \implies \tau = 1/\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 1):

In the second model, `tau <- sqrt(1/sigma)` is wrong; it should be `tau <- 1/sigma^2`.  You also cannot give a normal distribution to a non-negative random variable, so you will need to choose a different distribution for $\sigma$. If you simply want to keep the same form as `Model 1` but set your prior mean and variance for $\sigma$ to known values, this can be accomplished by checking the appropriate moments for the gamma prior and using some algebra to get the desired moments.