# Which prior on precision implies half-normal prior on sd?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, density-function

I am using software (INLA) that parametrizes the normal distribution via mean and precision. I noticed that my results are notably influenced by the choice of prior on precision, but I have hard time building intuition about precision. Instead I'd like to put half-normal prior on the standard deviation (sd) as I have intuition about that.

So we have

$$
\tau = 1/\sigma^2 \\
\sigma \sim HalfN(0, a) 
$$

with he PDF being

$$
f_\sigma(y;a) = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\exp \left( -\frac{y^2}{2a^2} \right)
$$

what is then the implied PDF $f_\tau$? Here's my attempt:

$$
F_\tau(y) = P(\tau \leq y) = P(\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \leq y) = P(\sigma \geq \sqrt{1/y}) = 1 - P(\sigma < \sqrt{1/y}) = \\ = 1 - F_\sigma(\sqrt{1/y})
$$

so we have
$$
f_\tau(y) = \frac{d}{dy} F_\tau(y) = - f_\sigma(\sqrt{1/y};a)(-\frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}) = \\
= \frac{1}{2}y^{-\frac{3}{2}}\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a\sqrt{\pi}}\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2 y a^2} \right) = \\
= \frac{y^{-\frac{3}{2}}}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2 y a^2} \right)
$$

Is that correct?

A similar question is at
[Defining prior on variance and not precision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/133364/defining-prior-on-variance-and-not-precision) but it has no complete answer.

Comment: The half-Normal is a $\chi(1)$ distribution: that is, it's proportional to the square root of a $\Gamma(1/2)$ distribution.  Thus https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-gamma_distribution is relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct; here's a similar way to show it. The half-normal prior on the standard deviation $\sigma$ (with scale $a$) is:

$$p_\sigma(\sigma) =
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{a \sqrt{\pi}} \exp \left( -\frac{\sigma^2}{2 a^2} \right)$$

The precision $\tau$ is related to the standard deviation as:

$$\tau = g(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma^2}$$

Since this is an invertible transformation (note that $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are non-negative), the prior on the precision can be found by applying the standard change of variables formula:

$$\begin{eqnarray}
  p_\tau(\tau) & = &
  p_\sigma \big( g^{-1}(\tau) \big) \left| \frac{d}{d\tau} g^{-1}(\tau) \right| \\
  & = & p_\sigma(\tau^{-\frac{1}{2}})
  \left| \frac{d}{d\tau} \tau^{-\frac{1}{2}} \right| \\
  & = & \frac{1}{2} \tau^{-\frac{3}{2}} p_\sigma(\tau^{-\frac{1}{2}})
\end{eqnarray}$$

Plugging in the formula for $p_\sigma(\cdot)$ yields the same answer you found:

$$p_\tau(\tau) =
\frac{1}{a \sqrt{2 \pi}} \tau^{-\frac{3}{2}}
\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2 a^2 \tau} \right)$$

This is an inverse gamma distribution with shape parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and scale parameter $\frac{1}{2 a^2}$